Versatile unlicensed use hand-held units
I'm doing a bit of research, as a newbie interested in a versatile walkie/HT to be used in Spain, mainly for mountaineering purposes. As far as I've read, it's possible to receive and emit in PMR446 (and CB? only?) with not even the HAREC exam. My question is about specific equipment suggestions (Baofeng or others) which may allow to emit only in those frequencies (with CTCSS and DCS, programmable channels, VOX, dual channel monitoring, preferably...) and, to avoid fines, only technically able to receive, but not to emit, in other bands. I.e., I would like to explore a bit and not get restricted to an exclusively PMR446, maybe locked DCS, walkie.
My concern is about many Baofeng models that will perfectly suit my needs but can emit in forbidden frequencies for me. After an (improbable) police check, I'm afraid they could fine me for carrying them.

Why not just buy a PMR446 Baofeng or similar? Seems they are easily available, (eg. amazon.de) for the usual price, have vox etc.

They're able to transmit outside the 446-446.2 MHz band, so not legal without license, in Spain. The most similar thing I found is the discontinued Retevis RB627B.

EU PMR446 Requirements
According to CEPT [emphasis added]

that all PMR 446 equipment is hand portable and shall use only integral antenna and an effective
radiated power not exceeding 500 mW, while any base station, repeater or fixed infrastructure use is
excluded

There are several other requirements documented there which I encourage you to check out.
Just PMR446 Radios
Most (all?) commercially available PMR446 radios are built with the uninitiated user in mind, and will not have any receive beyond PMR446 frequencies. Basically a single use appliance. Especially given the regulatory requirements.
Amateur radios (specifically, a Baofeng)
The integral antenna requirement imposed by CEPT seems to preclude Baofeng amateur radios (and probably all amateur radios).

Do you know for sure that Spain is as laid back as the US or UK? In South Africa for example, someone was prosecuted for listening to Air traffic control, while planespotting, without a license.

What I've read is not about listening but about owning without being able to prove you never emitted. It wouldn't probably be a problem, but the answer is really interesting. Disabling UHF Tx would keep it able to emit in PMR446?

That's what I was afraid of.  My idea is being able to use it normally in PMR446 and CB27 but having a unit unable to emit elsewhere. A unit specifically built for unlicensed people in Spain, I guess. But that's a possible approach, thanks!

Very helpful! Would it be better to open a new question to gather suggestions on some affordable and versatile units? E.g. those offering plenty of memory slots for channels and for CTCSS and DCS, configurability of the CTCSS and DCS, dual channel monitoring, VOX, squelch, batch configurable via PC, etc ideally a purely PMR446 Baofeng...

Unfortunately, questions soliciting specific product recommendations are prohibited on this site. I would recommend checking out the amateur radio subreddit which has several PMR446 related threads, and you can even start your own thread regarding your specific needs. A google search for "PMR446 reddit" seems to yield some helpful results.

I didn't intend, however, to have a specific recomendation but a list, if this kind of radios exist. The only similar walkie I found is a discontinued Retevis (RB627B), so I'm surprised, given the popularity of RPM446 band for those who are not licensed but require short range com solutions for mountaineering, surfing, skiing, hiking, climbing, ...
